# Using "this" in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS.

I have a select box that when clicked populates a second one. Probelem is that instead of doing it for the one item I wanted it to - it's updating the select boxes in all rows. Right now I am using forEach because I don't know how to use `this` in AngularJS:

```
    $scope.manufacturerUpdate = function(){

angular.forEach($scope.cams, function(cam){
    $scope.camslist = []
    $scope.camslist = cam.manufacturer.cameras;
    });

}
```

Clearly this is applying the newly selected first select box to all rows. How do I use the `this` in AngularJS so only the row I am editing is effected?

**Edit:** Here are the select boxes:

```
<select
       ng-model="cam.manufacturer"
       ng-options="manufacturers.name for manufacturers in manufacturers"  ng-change="manufacturerUpdate()">
       <option value="" selected="selected"> --Select a Manufacturer--</option>
</select>

            </td>
            <td>
                <select
       ng-model="cam.camera"
       ng-options="camslist.name for camslist in camslist"  ng-change="cameraUpdate()">
       <option value="" selected="selected"> --Select a Camera--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML for the select box? Select boxes require a bit of angular magic to work properly.

Comment: Could you post some more code or setup a JSFiddle?  It seems like your problem is that your scope is too broad, so affecting one item affects too much.  Solution could be as simple as making an isolate scope in your directive, but more code (specifically, your checkbox HTML and controller/directive code) would help.

Comment: Hi @MikeRobinson and Hylianpuffball - I updated the question to include the select.

Comment: Where is the functions that you call on ng-change? Can't you setup a fiddle?

Comment: @Beterraba - I updated the question to include the full function including `manufacturerUpdate()` which is what's being called with `ng-change`. The data is pulled from a file I'd like to keep private so I don't know if I can create a fiddle.

Comment: very helpful article http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/this-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this (and take out your JavaScript function). It's not perfect, but I think it'll work to get you moving along. If this doesn't work, please post an outline of how your $scope variables are set up as the references I'm listing here might not work with your data and could be adjusted:

```
<select
   ng-model="cam.manufacturer"
   ng-options="manufacturers.name for manufacturers in manufacturers">
   <option value="" selected="selected"> --Select a Manufacturer--</option>
</select>

</td>
<td>
<select
   ng-model="cam.camera"
   ng-options="camslist.name for camslist in cams[cam.manufacturer].camslist">
   <option value="" selected="selected"> --Select a Camera--</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think you put me on the right track but not quite yet. Here's what's happening.

`cam` is the name of the object. It has a few params, one of which is `manufacturer`. At the moment, `manufacturer` has in it `name` and an array called `cameras`. So what you're suggesting looks like it could work if I could get the syntax right. Not familiar with the square brackets. Given the info above - do you maybe have an updated version? I tried `camslist.name for camslist in cam.manufacturer[cameras]` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is to set camslist to the manufacturer's `.cameras`, which you can accomplish like this:

Template::

```
<ng-options="manufacturer.name for manufacturer in manufacturers"  ng-change="manufacturerUpdate(manufacturer)">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.manufacturerUpdate = function(manufacturer){
    $scope.camslist = manufacturer.cameras;
});
```

It's a bad idea to use the same variable name for the instance and the list name. It makes the code confusing, and does it even work?

Use:

```
cam.name for cam in camslist
```

Instead of:

```
camslist.name for camslist in camslist
```

Comment: Okay this is incredibly close to working (HUGE thanks). The only thing seems to be that cam is not defined in the `$scope.camslist = cam.manufacturer`.cameras; statement. technically, shouldn't the `cam.` act as the `"this"` in this case (and work?) In `angular.forEach` functions I used `angular.forEach(oldCams, function(cam)` and then used `cam`. Should I be using a `(cam, manufacturer)` in the `manufacturerUpdate` function?

Comment: Hey @noa - it can't find cameras of undefined. Which means that manufacturer is not being carried over to the function.

Comment: Are you passing `manufacturer` in the call to manufacturerUpdate in your template?

Comment: I think that's the piece I'm missing. How do I do that? Currently I have 

`<select
       ng-model="cam.manufacturer"
       ng-options="manufacturer.name for manufacturer in manufacturers" ng-change="manufacturerUpdate(manufacturer)">
       <option value="" selected="selected"> --Select a Manufacturer--</option>
</select>`

Comment: OKAY! As usual the solution was simpler than I thought - and you helped by making me focus on the `ng-options` instead of a function. So the issue was I needed to refer to the cam.manufacturer model in the camera select. so I made it `cam.name for cam in cam.manufacturer.cameras` and it works PERFECTLY.

Comment: noa - your answer wasn't the solution. But if you want to take the info from my comment above and update your answer I will gladly upvote it and checkmark it.